# Getting an event source (The node with the attached listener), when the event listener is added within another event

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Ok, this feels like a basic question, but I can't find any info, so here I go.

So I've got a function (`addNewNode(event)`) that creates a `<li>` node, and appends it to a `<ul>`. This function is triggered by clicking a button. The `<li>` node also has an event listener (`removeThisNode(event)`) attached to it when it is appended to the `<ul>` children, so that it ca nbe removed later.

I need to get the `<li>` node in the `removeThisNode(event)` function. The event.target is the button in this case. How do I get the `<li>` node? Do I have to pass the `<li>` node I just created into it's own event listener? Is there another way (Without jquery)?

(EDIT) Sample :

```
var addNewNode = function(){
    var ulNode = document.getElementById("data-list");
    var newLiNode = document.createElement("LI");
    newLiNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode("test text"));
    newLiNode.addEventListener("click",function(event){removeThisNode(event)})
    ulNode.appendChild(newLiNode);
}

var removeThisNode = function(event){
    var liNode = event.target; // <-- liNode comes up as the button in the debugger
    liNode.parent.removeChild(liNode);
}

window.onload = function(){
    var button = document.getElementById("add-data-button");
    button.addEventListener("click",function(){addNewNode()});
}
```

Comment: It would be much easy to solve and understand if you'd post a sample. On stack or www.jsbin.com or www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

Oops, false alarm. I was passing the event parameter from one eventListener (the button click) to the next, so it was keeping the event.target the same!

```
var addNewNode = function(event){ //it was taking this event parameter
    var ulNode = document.getElementById("data-list");
    var newLiNode = document.createElement("LI");
    newLiNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode("test text"));
    newLiNode.addEventListener("click",function(event){removeThisNode(event)}) // <-into here
    ulNode.appendChild(newLiNode);
}
```

Comment: Trying to explain others the problem kinda helps you figure out the solution.